# How do I move my spawn point?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am spawning too far from my home. How do I move my spawn point?

Comment: In Survival MP, use /sethome

Comment: In Notch's March 28 blog [post](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/4159257708/full-steam-ahead-captain) he says next update will include spawn change.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Minecraft Beta 1.4 and later, [sleeping in a bed](https://twitter.com/jeb_/status/50550632528097280) will set your spawn point.

On older SMP servers running Minecraft Beta 1.3, spawn points can be changed using the /setspawn command, provided the server is running any of the common mods to provide this functionality. Sometimes this command is called /sethome, and sometimes the /sethome command has a different purpose.

There is no way to set the spawn point ingame on Single Player Minecraft Alpha/Beta < 1.4. Some third party tools will change it for you however.

For Minecraft Classic, pressing Enter sets the spawn point.

Comment: Good find, that twitter post.

Comment: As 1.4 is now out, the changelog confirms this: " Sleeping in a bed now resets your spawn position" (also added to my answer, below)

Answer (score 17):

Simply make a [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) and lay into it. If you're in multiplayer mode, you don't need to wait for all others to also get in a bed in order to sleep - laying down is enough to change your spawn point *so long as your bed doesn't get destroyed*.

Comment: Also, Nether Portals!

Comment: I have a network of tunnels and houses, but no mine tracks as yet, though I think I've got enough iron now.

Comment: a video to nether portals http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7pySDFxCCc

Answer (score 13):

You can't do this without cheating.

If you're okay with cheating, you can use [NBTEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=7868) using [this guide](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=19493).

Comment: MC Edit also has this functionality, I believe.

Comment: As of the time of this comment, the functionality appears to not work in MCEdit.

Answer (score 5):

> The location of the spawn point can be changed if the player digs 3 spaces downwards from it. This will however only move the spawn point a few blocks away from the original location; it is not possible, using this method, to dramatically or controllably alter the location of the spawn point but there is tools that allows you to change the spawn point.

From https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn

Comment: @Tobias: Also: the answer -> *your own answer*

Comment: @Tobias, maybe, if you dig the *whole chunk* around your spawnpoint, down to **bedrock** - you can *slowly* push your spawnpoint to your house... :)

Comment: Ah, cool - I'd remove my downvote, but it gets locked in after an hour, or until the post is edited again (so if you modify the post I can un-downvote).

Answer (score 5):

An idea similar to the [badp answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10475/how-to-set-a-new-spawn-point/10530#10530):

Build a river from somewhere near your spawn point to your house. This way, the water flow will help you move fast toward your house. It's also very cheap to build.

Answer (score 4):

In the next minecraft update, players will be able to move their spawn point.

Source: http://notch.tumblr.com/

> I’ve been able to focus on development
>   a lot the last couple of weeks, and
>   we’re hoping to get the new update out
>   soon. It will include the wolves, the
>   ability to change your spawn point,
>   and a rather ambitious statistics
>   tracking and achievement system.

And, officially, from the changelog:

> Sleeping in a bed now resets your
>   spawn position

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wanna spawn too far away from your house
make a bed:

```
(wool wool wool)
(wood wood wood)
```

or put up a signal thats above the clouds, it will be like a pin on a treasure map.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Minecraft (tested on 1.8.9) you can use

```
/setworldspawn X Y Z
```

where X, Y and Z are coordinates, where you want to set the spawn point. You can easily check your current coordinates e.g. with debugging screen (press `F3`).

You can learn more about the command with

```
/help setworldspawn
```

Answer (score -1):

/setworldspawn
(works if you have commands on)

Comment: Do you think you could explain why `/setworldspawn` works? Clue: Added feature in 1.7

Answer (score -2):

Create a bed in a well lit, well protected area.

Beware: a natural occurrence called "nightmares" might occur.Nightmares are random spawning of spiders, skeletons, or zombies near your bed. Sometimes sleeping underground solves the problem of too many nightmare occurrences. Make sure the area is well lit!

Comment: Nightmares actually only happen if you sleep in an unsafe bed. See: [How can I avoid mobs spawning in my house while I sleep?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/how-can-i-avoid-mobs-spawning-inside-my-house-while-i-sleep)

Comment: This answer is obsolete -- Now you cannot sleep if monsters are near