# How can I avoid mobs spawning inside my house while I sleep?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The latest Minecraft update now has beds, which is very nice for the first few nights of the game while you establish a mob-resistant area that you can work in during the night.

For reference, you sleep in a bed during the nighttime and it fast-forwards to daylight.

My problem is that I've put down a bed, and every time I sleep in it I get woken up by mobs *inside my house*. I've made sure it's very light, darkened it a bit - tried a few combinations but no luck.

What am I missing? How can I avoid having mobs spawning inside my house every time I try and get some sleep?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed), aggressive mobs won't wake you if you surround your bed with torches. Here is what it says about the mob behavior:

> To ensure that you are not awakened unnecessarily during the night, the bed must not be placed along a 1 block thick wall, unless the area on the other side of the wall is also safe. If a hostile mob can get within 2 blocks of the bed, even if the blocks are separated by a wall, you will be awakened with the hostile mob standing next to you. There appears to be a slight delay before the mob attacks you, giving you time to get the first blow.

---

**Edit**: As of Minecraft 1.0, mobs will not awaken you suddenly if your bed is placed in an unideal location. Instead, the game won't let you sleep and will state that there are mobs nearby.

Comment: "the bed must not be placed along a 1 block thick wall, unless the area on the other side of the wall is also safe" <-- That's my problem, right there. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the 1 block thick thing work?

Comment: "|" = wall, "B" = bed; |B = bad, ||B = good.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problems, and my bed was nowhere near a wall. The room was well lit, and I couldn't figure out the problem was. I finally found it in the wiki:

> If you use your bed, and **have a door with a right hinge** (as viewed from the outside), monsters can still get to you and wake you up, as though no door was present. One example of this is **a room with double doors, atleast one of the doors will be unsafe**.

D'oh!

Comment: *"a room with double doors, at least one of the doors will be unsafe"* – not necessarily true; my house has double doors and I'm fine sleeping. It's not so much that a right-hinge door is the problem, but that both doors should lay flush with the outside wall.

Answer (score 7):

Jeb recently tweeted the following:

> [New bed behavior... Instead of being woken up by monsters, you are not allowed to sleep if monsters are nearby. Once you sleep you're safe](http://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/134678081456709632)

This means that as of Minecraft's official release next week, you will never have to worry about being woken by monsters again. \o/

Answer (score 5):

It is [believed](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/sleeping_in_a_bed_sometimes_causes_a_mob_to_spawn_next_to_you) that the game sometimes cause a "nightmare" when you sleep, spawning a monster even in safe places.

However, for some people, monsters spawn more often than should. Possible reasons are bugs in nightmare code (triggering too often), or game detecting the place as unsafe even when the player thinks it is safe. There are a few topics at GetSatisfaction about this issue:

- [Monsters wake you up while in bed](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/monsters_wake_you_up_while_in_bed)
- [CANT SLEEP, MOBS WILL EAT ME! or just spawn next to my bed.](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/cant_sleep_mobs_will_eat_me_or_just_spawn_next_to_my_bed)
- [Sleeping in a bed sometimes causes a mob to spawn next to you!](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/sleeping_in_a_bed_sometimes_causes_a_mob_to_spawn_next_to_you)

Comment: Do you have a source on that nightmare comment? I don't find it believable that they want it to occur in totally safe areas.

Comment: It has been mentioned a few times in: http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/sleeping_in_a_bed_sometimes_causes_a_mob_to_spawn_next_to_you , but I can't find an official statement.

Comment: Well, until I see an official statement, I don't see any reason to think it's intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Mobs spawn in a 3x3x3 area, so build a house like 10x10x2 or place blocks so that there is no 3x3x3 area is in your house; this way, no mobs can spawn.

Comment: This is currently outdated, mobs only need 1x2x1 block to spawn. 1 wide 2 high.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put  your bed near a wall, like this guy.[image: Look at his bed, how it is not near a wall.]

Comment: See how is bed IS NOT near a wall?

Comment: The head of the bed is touching the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Make each room smaller than 3 blocks tall and put a lot of touches down if the rooms are over a certain area, I think its an area of more than 3 by 3 will spawn mobs, if the light levels are less than level 7 mobs will spawn in them.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a little more? looks so vague ...

Answer (score -2):

Just put dirt or some other block over the window part of the door, on BOTH SIDES, and try your bed. if it doesn't work, cover your windows in the same fashion.

Comment: Nope, this dodes not work.