# How do I place a bed in Minecraft so no mobs spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I avoid mobs spawning inside my house while I sleep?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/how-can-i-avoid-mobs-spawning-inside-my-house-while-i-sleep)

In what way should I put the bed and how must the surroundings be in order for mobs to not spawn when I am sleeping?

Comment: I think you'll find this question has already been answered quite thoroughly through the above link!

Comment: The link is missing...

Comment: DemonicMushy, please stop rolling this question back to remove the Exact Duplicate link at the top. Your question has already been asked before and it's important that other people see that it has been, so they can get answers to this question even if they find this unanswered duplicate. Prosay, please stop adding engaging in an edit war adding nonsense tags to this question.