# underground home

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I avoid mobs spawning inside my house while I sleep?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/how-can-i-avoid-mobs-spawning-inside-my-house-while-i-sleep)

So, i'm making my real pad (home) underground, if I place a bed next to a wall underground, will monsters show up next to me? Additionally, how I keep monsters out of my house, place a block in front (but inside your home) of the door?

Answer (score 2):

I always build my house underground at first, it makes it easier to wall off the entrance for night time on the first few nights.

To be (relatively) safe, I recommend lighting as much of the surrounding tunnels as possible. On particular choke points down these tunnels (for example, 3x3 tunnels) wall off with some blocks and a door).

I typically make a 4x4x3 bedroom with a door (a block to start with, then I move to an iron door)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the bed piece to your house depends on how far a monster is from you. If you have a home that has no exposed holes, then you should be fine. Before, if you had your bed too close to the wall, monsters would wake you up in the middle of the night. There should be no need for the block in front of your door if you use an iron door. If you are playing on Hard difficulty, you should use an iron door because zombies can break wooden ones on Easy. If you followed all of the above, as well as some tips [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials) from the Minecraft Wiki, then you should have a good night's sleep. Monsters spawning also depend on if there Are any light sources nearby and if you are close to a cave, Abandoned Mineshaft, etc. If the monsters scare you, you could change your difficulty to Peaceful so that no monsters spawn and you can continue working throughout the night.

Answer (score 1):

Mobs won't show up next to you as long as you have sufficient lighting (lighting level 7 or more, torches produce light level 14). All you need to do to stop them spawning is to pop up a couple of torches in your bedroom and make sure to have a door (or block up a doorway) so that mobs that have spawned else-ware don't wander in to spoil your nap.

As a side not, you may sometimes get the error "can't sleep there are monsters nearby", this happens to me often while i'm sleeping in a cave I've made. It just means that either above, below or to the side of you there is a cave or opening where a mob has discovered you, just dig around a bit, have a bit of murder and then you can rest easy.

I hope this has helped, happy mining!