# What are the mob spawn distances?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have built my house in Minecraft PE, and I have a ton of fences and sticks, but I need to know how big of a perimeter I need to let me sleep at night?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid mobs spawning inside my house while I sleep?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/how-can-i-avoid-mobs-spawning-inside-my-house-while-i-sleep)

Comment: [There appears to be quite a few differences between the Pocket Edition and the 360/PC version](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Pocket_Edition). Due to this I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi, @GeloDCastroid, I've edited your question to add in a bit of punctuation and taken the game name out of the title.  That's done to eliminate the redundancy for SEO.

Comment: SEO? and if you are going to answer (cough @Wipqozn cough) then answer, don't comment.

Comment: I'd recommend reading our [about page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about).  We work a little differently than most other gaming sites.  An overriding rule across the SE network (of which Arqade is a part of) is, "Be nice".  We are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sleep if there are hostile or mobs that are neutral but are now aggressive within **8 blocks** of your bed. Neutral but can be aggressive include wolves, enderman, and zombie pigman. Do keep in mind that there might be mobs hidden underground. Also be sure to light the area up as mobs can still spawn in your base if not properly lit.

Answer (score -2):

I've played PE a lot and have a rough idea of the radius of monster spawning. I think that in PE, monsters can't spawn in a radius of about 15-20 blocks and the zone of monsters not able to spawn is about... 60 blocks after the normal no monster spawning radius. Note that this information may not be very accurate and uses rough estimates by the looks from where I am.

Comment: Using "roughly" and "about" and "I think" doesn't help anyone.  Try to back up your answer with canonical references or sources.